# How to dynamically update object key in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I'm creating a React project that stores data in Firebase, it pulls data from Firebase on every refresh.

I'm trying to make it so that when I add a new comment, React State dynamically updates the object key in State. If you see the screenshot below, see the `comments_text` object, I want to make the key `comment` be simply `2` instead of `comment`.

[image]

When I refresh the page, Firebase (I think it's Firebase) dynamically updates the keys (0, 1, 2, 3 etc...). But I'm currently hard coding the object key to be `comment` when updating the React state. Please see React/Redux code below...

```
    case HOLD_COMMENT_POST:
        {
          const { postUserId, postId, commenter_comment, commenter_handle, commenter_uid, comment_key } = action.payload;

          return state.map((user) => {
            if (user.uid === postUserId) {

              return {
                ...user,
                posts: user.posts.map(post => {
                  if (post.key === postId) {

                    return {
                      ...post,
                      comments_text: post.comments_text ? {...post.comments_text, comment: {commenter_comment: commenter_comment, commenter_handle: commenter_handle, commenter_uid: commenter_uid, key: comment_key}} : {comment: {comment: commenter_comment, handle: commenter_handle, uid: commenter_uid, key: comment_key}}
                    };
                  } else {
                    return post;
                  }
                })
              }
            }
            else {
              return user;
            }
          })
        }
```

Is there a way to dynamically update the key? I realize it's currently hard coded to display `comment`, but I would prefer it updates to the next sequential number (2, 3, 4 etc...)

Lastly, my code is currently working, no bugs (that I know of). I'm just concerned that hard coding the key will cause issues later on. Is it actually okay to leave it as is if there is no issue? Whenever I refresh the page, the keys are automatically dynamically updated to be sequential numbers. For consistency, I would just prefer the key dynamically updates on React state updates.

Please let me know if you need more details. Thank you for reviewing.

Comment: `comment_text` looks like an array to me, is it not?

Comment: It's not, it's an object

Comment: `const lastKey = Object.keys(comment_text).filter(key => Number.isInteger(+key)).pop()` I believe this one-liner can help you determine the last numerical key.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help. I ended up using this ```const total_comments  = post.comments_text ?  Object.keys(post.comments_text).length : 0;```